# How to create a PowerApp gallery with multiple dataset lists

Tags: list, sharepoint, powerapps

I am trying to use data stored in multiple lists from a SharePoint collection, and display the data stored inside all of the lists within a PowerApp gallery.

The fields I want to pick from the lists are all the same I would just like to display them within a PowerApp gallery.

Is this possible using PowerApps?

Any help or insight into this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Different ways you can achieve this, by joining the data or by collecting data first. By using Lookup function, you can join the data first. Please refer to this [article.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Can-I-add-fields-from-multiple-data-sources-into-a-single/td-p/7376) And use Collect function is very straightforward, you will collect the fields into the same collection and use the collection as the data source of your gallery. Example code:

`Collect(CombinedCollection, 'table1'.Title); Collect(CombinedCollection, 'table2'.Title)`:

Comment: So does this function rest within  a tile in the PowerApp? Where should I insert the function?